# What is the name of the shape generated by the vertices of the Soviet pennant on the Luna 2 spacecraft? Is it an polyhedron?

Tags: polyhedra, solid-geometry

[xkcd 2125](https://xkcd.com/2125/) titled "Luna 2" refers to the object shown below. All faces seem to be pentagons. (found in [this question](https://gizmodo.com/collecting-samples-from-asteroid-bennu-may-be-harder-th-1833412210).)

[image: xkcd.com/2125/ Soviet pennant Luna 2]

[image: Soviet pennant Luna 2]

Copy of the Soviet pennant sent on the Luna 2 probe to the moon, at the Kansas Cosmosphere, [Source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Kansas_Cosmosphere_Luna_2_Pennant_2013.JPG)

---

**Question:** What is the name of the polyhedral shape of the Soviet pennant on the Luna 2 spacecraft?

**note:** This question is about the shape without the spherical caps, the way that the underlying shape of a football is a truncated icosahedron. In this case though I am not sure if this shape will be a polyhedron or not as the five vertices of the pentagonal faces may not lay in a plane.

[image]

"Comparison of a truncated icosahedron with the typical appearance of a football/soccer ball." [Source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Comparison_of_truncated_icosahedron_and_soccer_ball.png)

Comment: modeled after the question [What is the name of the polyhedral shape of the Humanity Star?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2620066/284619)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as a 72 faced object, it's a [canonical](https://www.georgehart.com/virtual-polyhedra/canonical.html) pentagonal [heptacontakaidihedron](http://www.topcatmath.com/docs/Math106/Math106.Classroom.Activity02.doc) or [dokaiheptacontaheron](https://robertlovespi.net/2014/08/16/a-pentagonal-dokaiheptacontaheron/)

In [Conway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_polyhedron_notation) terms, it's a spherical quinto dodecahedron 'C969qD' 
[image: spherical quinto dodecahedron]
[play with it here](https://levskaya.github.io/polyhedronisme/?recipe=C969qD&palette=%23eeeeee%20%23999999%20%23000099%20)

However, I've not seen much about quinto [outside the wikidpedia page and that viewer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Conway_polyhedron_notation#Original_research), so I'm no longer so sure about it. Another Conway recipe, 't5oD' is very similar.

Comment: I've just asked [How to understand the Conway recipe C969qD to construct this polyhedron? Canonicalization then quinto?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3158935/284619)

Answer (score 2):

Ball.

> In the collection of our museum there are two unique samples that were delivered to the moon in the area of ​​the Sea of ​​Rains near Aristill, Archimedes and Autolycus. These two balls consisted of pentagonal steel segments. A larger ball (150 mm) was installed on the third stage, a smaller ball (90 mm) - on a container with equipment. For each ball there were 72 pentagons of two types - regular (12 pcs.) And irregularly shaped (60 pcs.). Inside the hollow balls housed explosives. There was a shock fuse that caused luck on the land of the moon. With the explosion of the pennants scattered in all directions, like shards. Falling speed, and they should remain on the surface. All space pennants were minted at the Leningrad Mint.

From http://www.kosmo-museum.ru/news/lunnye-vympely-sssr

[image]

Comment: Uhoh, I believe that @A.Rumlin gave interesting information that was lacking in your original post: the ball has 12 regular pentagons and 60 irregular pentagons. (I have no idea if that shape has a name.)

Comment: @Ertxiem Oh, I understand what you mean; yes that's very useful. Thanks!

Comment: @uhoh The Humanity Star  surface consists of several flat triangles. In case of Luna-2 - These plates have a convex shape - like spherical cap.

Comment: I see what you mean now. I've made an adjustment to the question loosening it up a bit by using the analogy of a football versus a truncated icosahedron. Yes the football is a "ball" but we can understand that it is vertex-by-vertex linked to a truncated icosahedron. This was my intention and I should have understood it wasn't clear without stating explicitly. The information in your answer is very helpful, thanks!

Comment: @A.Rumlin Thinking further, when you say "72 pentagons" I'm wondering if for each one, do all five points fall within a plane?

Comment: @uhoh On the photo from the museum you can see separate plates attached to the blue fabric. Look like all five points fall within a plane

Comment: This image is in very high resolution. I do not know whether the image will be automatically reduced to an acceptable size on this page .

Comment: @uhoh main_large_IMG_1793.JPG Failed to upload image; the format is not supported

Comment: It worked for me the first time, sometimes you need to try twice.