# How to understand the Conway recipe C969qD to construct this polyhedron? Canonicalization then quinto?

Tags: polyhedra, geometric-construction

The [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3158009/284619) to my previous question about the shape below is the [Conway notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_polyhedron_notation) `C969qD`.

Per the [linked viewer](https://levskaya.github.io/polyhedronisme/?recipe=C969qD&palette=%23eeeeee%20%23999999%20%23000099%20) in that answer:

> The specification consists of a space-delimited series of polyhedral recipes. Each recipe looks like:
>
> [op][op] ... [op][base] no spaces, just a string of characters

I thought I might try to read through the notation to see if I could try to do this manually by manipulating shapes in [Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/) + Python, but I've gotten stuck trying to parse the procedure into steps that I can understand.

The operation is read right to left so the base is `D` which is `dodecahedron`, followed by some polyhedron-building operators `C969q`.

The final operator `C969` is intriguing:

> CN - proper Canonicalization, intensive, slow convergence, iteratively refines shape N times. Flattens faces. A typical N is 200 or 300.

**Question:** What exactly is it that needs to be done 969 times? Then how to apply `q` for `quinto`? All I see on the page is Thanks to "Lei Willems - for inventing quinto."

I see several dodecahedrons [here](http://dmccooey.com/polyhedra/index.html) for example, but no *quinto*.

---

[image: convex heptacontakidigon Conway C969qD]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conway notation works right to left, as explained in the linked wikipedia page.

"quinto" -- as explained on the viewer page, but not the wikipedia page, replaces every face with a truncated pyramid, the faces of which are five sided. remove the C969 to see that.

The canonicalisation process isn't Conway, but attempts to convert the shape into as regular a shape as possible following an algorithm (basically make the vertices as equidistant as possible and convex). This implementation takes 969 iterations to converge the shape this implementaion makes for a qD. If you were to reduce the value to 968, you'd see a single blue face, which wasn't quite the same shape as the other 59 irregular polygons

k5oD also works - start with dodecahedron [D], create an edge orthogonal to every edge (o) (here this replaces every face with a pyramid, each face of which has four edges) then truncate all vertices with 5 edges (t5) - as it happens that construction, in that viewer, doesn't need any processing to make it ball-ish. The Conway wikipedia page talks about other methods of constructing a quinto-dodecahedron.

It so happens Conway operators have been implemented in Blender as a [plug-in](http://elfnor.com/conway-polyhedron-operators-in-sverchok.html), but the viewer linked allows you to play with the different operators.

Comment: tI will be slow going for me but this definitely helps, thank you!

Comment: Oh that looks really interesting, and I thought I'd get something done today; oh well.